# Как сделать просмотр 3д моделей на сайте?

Tags: javascript, 3d

Как реализована функция просмотра 3d моделей на этом сайте http://armory.warmane.com/character/Apparent/Lordaeron/summary , есть мб какие-то библиотеки js по 3д моделированию или готовые решения?

Comment: Там canvas используется, а сама функция доступна по этому адресу: http://cdn.warmane.com/modelviewer/viewer.js?v=1466252249
Так же интересен вопрос о библиотеках или документации.

Comment: Есть, например, http://threejs.org/ - фреймвок использующий WebGL. На armory.warmane.com похоже используется что-то свое с использованием WebGL

Answer (score 3):

Для просмотра 3D моделей, сперва их надо загрузить (или импортировать) в приложение. Импортирование подразумаевает банальное считывание данных из файла содержащего все необходимые данные, а именно:

**Аттрибуты вершины (vertex attributes)**

1. позиции вершин в локальной системе координат `(x, y, z)`
2. нормалей к вершинам `(x, y, z)`
3. текстурные координаты `(x, y), 0 <= x, y <= 1`

**Информацию о материалах модели** (Ambient, Diffuse, Specular составляющие каждого материала)

1. `Ambient` `Ka` - степень материала воспринимать фоновый свет.
2. `Diffuse` `Kd` - (рассеивающая) составляющая материала, показывает степень материала воспринимать рассеивающий свет - тот свет который в зависимости от ориентации (нормали) поверхности и направления света рассеивается во все стороны равномерно.
3. `Specular` `Ks` - свойство материала воспринимать зеркальный свет

Например, если представить себе модель какой-либо машины - то там обивка салона это один материал, шины другой материал, кузов вобще другой (например матовый), а диски блестят.

кусок из `.mtl` файла

```
# Blender MTL File: 'modelname.blend'
# Material Count: 6
newmtl Arm
Ns 96.078431
Ka 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000
Kd 0.640000 0.640000 0.640000
Ks 0.500000 0.500000 0.500000
Ni 1.000000
d 1.000000
illum 2
map_Kd arm_dif.png
map_Bump arm_showroom_ddn.png
map_Ks arm_showroom_spec.png 

// ...
```

**Текстуры** - изображения (images) в каком либо формате для текстурирования с помощью текстурных координат.

В случае с `js` импортированием будет разбор (или парсинг) файла экспортированного из какого - либо 3D редактора содержащего данные (аттрибуты вершин, текстуры) о модели. Этот файл сервер должен отдавать клиенту в виде `plain/text` или `application/json` или `application/javascript`.

Есть решения которые делают всю рутинную работу связанную с считыванинем (или парсингом), и как уже упомянули о `three.js` добавлю, что он включает в себя подобные решения (инструменты или `loader`ы) некоторые из них:

[`OBJLoader`](http://threejs.org/docs/index.html?q=Loader#Reference/Loaders/OBJLoader)
[`MTLLoader`](http://threejs.org/docs/index.html?q=Loader#Reference/Loaders/MTLLoader)
[`ColadaLoder`](http://threejs.org/docs/index.html?q=Loader#Reference/Loaders/ColladaLoader)
[`glTFloader`](http://threejs.org/docs/index.html?q=Loader#Reference/Loaders/glTFLoader)
[`JSONLoader`](http://threejs.org/docs/index.html?q=Loader#Reference/Loaders/JSONLoader)
[`MaterialLoader`](http://threejs.org/docs/index.html?q=Loader#Reference/Loaders/MaterialLoader)

Если вершины с аттрибутами в `.obj` файле то обычно инфа о материалах и текстуры идут в отдельном `.mtl` файле, потому и столько различных лоадеров.